# Including and grouping related functions in js files in Node Express

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a Node Express route file. It was getting large in its number of functions that weren't route related - code to hit Azure and other file name related functions.

I'm fairly sure I want to keep routing functions in the route file (here it's `route/tally.js` file, and functions for file name parsing in another file (i.e. `fileName.js` and `tallyAzure.js`).

1. How can I tell my route.js file to include and refer all the functions that live inside another .js file.

   With the route js file, I've tried `include("routes/tallyAzure.js");`.
2. Where's the most logical place in the solution to put these function files? I'm leaning towards a dir outside of the `routes` dir. Any naming conventions that I should be aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `exports` variable. Here's an example from the documentation at: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

**circle.js:**

```
var PI = Math.PI;

exports.area = function (r) {
  return PI * r * r;
};

exports.circumference = function (r) {
  return 2 * PI * r;
};
```

**app.js:**

```
var circle = require('./circle.js');
console.log( 'The area of a circle of radius 4 is '
           + circle.area(4));
```